# Probability of guessing password of at least one user out of 500,000, with only 3 attempts on each user

Tags: probability

- There are 500,000 users
- Every user's password is exactly 7 digits (0-9)
- After 3 attempts the account is locked.

The probability of guessing any particular user's password would be `3/10,000,000`, but how would I calculate the probability that an attacker could gain access to at least one account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p=3/10^7$ be probability of guessing the password for user $i$.

Assuming you are truly guessing (that is, you are simply punching in random digits), the probability you do not guess the password for user $i$ is $1-p$. Thus, the probability you do not guess password for *any* user is $(1-p)^{500,000}$ (these are just independent events). Thus probability you guess password for at least one user is $1-(1-p)^{500,000}\approx 0.139$.